# SSO bot for Teams errors- "Failed to authorise due to error"

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

[image: error message during installation]

I am testing the sample provided at
https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/d5e04d254c823031369af81d523b7dd041c9e44a/samples/19.c.single-sign-on-for-teams-apps

I have setup the app on the appStudio as suggested and have the Bot and Web node scripts running while I get this error. And the error pops up as soon as I hit the install button on the appStudio.

Please can someone advice the reason for this issue and what needs fixed

Comment: Are you trying to do SSO for Bot? SSO for Bots is not currently supported. Could you please try this in Teams web app and check if there are any console errors?

Comment: This sample is actually of a webpage with chat window, which is suppose to be accessible through Teams tabs- is this what you have meant by "Teams web app"? Please help to clarify. Secondly, this webpage I am building is opened in teams and not a browser, so are you suggesting me to run a different sample for testing in browser so that I can see the console errors if any?

Comment: Please try login into teams in a browser. Open any browser and go to https://teams.microsoft.com and try to get the console errors by pressing F12.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I finally closed down to the point where the call back URL had a typo in it. And as the reply was sent to an invalid URL, I suppose that is why it errored.